# Trocando de partial por script sem recarregar a aplicação Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, estava fazendo uns testes. E caso eu queira fazer uma condicional para um único botão mandar para uma Partial passando um parâmetro, ou não. E fiz um button chamando esta função:
Controller

```
$scope.continuar = function(){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getbyemail/teste@teste.com')
        .success(function(retorno) {
            console.log(retorno);
            $scope.infos = retorno;
            if (retorno.usuarioId){
                console.log("Vai passar COM o parametro");
                window.location.href = "pagina/usuarioId";
            } else {
                console.log("Vai passar SEM o parametro");
                window.location.href = "pagina";
            }
        })
        .error(function(erro) {
            console.log(erro);
        });
    };
```

Deu certo, ele passou, MAS, ele recarregou a minha aplicação, e meu intuito é realmente usar o SPA, ambas as partials fazem parte da mesma aplicação. Eu não queria recarrega-la.

Há algum modo de fazer isto?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar a resposta :)

ao invés de usar o código javascript

```
 window.location.href = "pagina/usuarioId";
```

Agora uso:

```
$location.path("pagina/" + usuarioId);
```

e ele troca apenas a view :)